# What is the meaning of とも in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, usage

I need some help with the meaning of とも in this sentence

> とも言えますが

I have tried looking the definition up but it doesn't seem to fit in this context.

I have the first part roughly translated as

> because its a time like this,

but the second part I'm not sure of.  I know that the second part roughly translates to

> it can be said/one can say

but I'm still not sure what the function of
とも is here.

For context here is the whole sentence.

> こんな時だから, とも言えますが, 四大会議四大国の王が集う唯一の機会

Answer (score 2, accepted):

と is the "quotation" particle. も is nothing more than just the particle you use when you want to say "me too" (add up a thing or a person) -> 私も or exaggerate something -> 二回もやった（けど、...).

In this case, とも言えます basically means "we could also say...".

As for the beginning of the sentence, this is not really part of the question, but you could put こんな時だから, inside parentheses if it helps you understand it better:

> 「こんな時だから、...」とも言えますが、...